# how to pass a string/object in a require

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, require

I want to pass a string in javascript module

module1.js

```
  var currency = 'dollar'
  module = require('./module2')(currency)
```

How can I do that because right now I have this error

`TypeError: string is not a function e=[TypeError:string is not a function]`

Thanks you all

Answer (score 1):

```
 var currency = 'dollar'
 module = require('./module2').yourFunction(currency);
```

Comment: Depends on what is exposed..Isn't it ? What if `module.exports = function expression;` ?

Comment: I am asking things mate..Just to get my assumptions right! My guess is `require('./module2')` returns some `string` that `object`..

Comment: @Omarjmh what should I put as in this function yourFunction in order to save or return currency ? thx

Answer (score 0):

I think You have to build function inside module and than call it after require it, it is better solution for your problem
    **change.js**

```
module.exports = {
  escape: function(html) {
    return String(html)
      .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
      .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
      .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
      .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
      .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
  }
```

> call it this way

```
var change= require("change");
change.escape(yourElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass currency as a parameter to a function in module2 use:

module = require('./module2').FunctionName(currency);

If you want to access a property by name currency ('dollar' property in this case) in module2 use:

module = require('./module2')[currency];

Comment: Awesome, I dont have any crash, but how can I have access to the variable in module2 ? thx

Comment: @radjiv : Lets say your module2.js is as below
module.exports = {
  variable1: { 
  }
}
 
 To access variable1 use
 module = require('./module2')['variable1'];